# Plotting Pandas groupby groups using subplots and loop

Tags: python, pandas, plot, subplot, pandas-groupby

I am trying to generate a grid of subplots based off of a Pandas groupby object.  I would like each plot to be based off of two columns of data for one group of the groupby object. Fake data set:

```
C1,C2,C3,C4
1,12,125,25
2,13,25,25
3,15,98,25
4,12,77,25
5,15,889,25
6,13,56,25
7,12,256,25
8,12,158,25
9,13,158,25
10,15,1366,25
```

I have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv   
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

#Path to CSV File
path = "..\\fake_data.csv"

#Read CSV into pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(path)

#GroupBy C2
grouped = df.groupby('C2')

#Figure out number of rows needed for 2 column grid plot
#Also accounts for odd number of plots
nrows = int(math.ceil(len(grouped)/2.))

#Setup Subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows,2)

for ax in axs.flatten():
    for i,j in grouped:
        j.plot(x='C1',y='C3', ax=ax)

plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

But it generates 4 identical subplots with all of the data plotted on each (see example output below):

[image]

I would like to do something like the following to fix this:

```
for i,j in grouped:
    j.plot(x='C1',y='C3',ax=axs)
    next(axs)
```

but I get this error

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'

I will have a dynamic number of groups in the groupby object I want to plot, and many more elements than the fake data I have provided. This is why I need an elegant, dynamic solution and each group data set plotted on a separate subplot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want to iterate over the groups and the axes *in parallel*, so rather than having nested `for` loops (which iterates over all groups for *each* axis), you want something like this:

```
for (name, df), ax in zip(grouped, axs.flat):
    df.plot(x='C1',y='C3', ax=ax)
```

[image]

You have the right idea in your second code snippet, but you're getting an error because `axs` is an array of axes, but `plot` expects just a single axis. So it should also work to replace `next(axs)` in your example with `ax = axs.next()` and change the argument of `plot` to `ax=ax`.